# FFmpeg takes too much time for generating m3u8 files from a mp4 file (166MB)

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, encoding, m3u8

I am using ffmpeg in nodejs to generate 4 different resolutions (360p, 480p, 720p, 1080p).
I use a AWS lambda for each resolution and the last two take too much time.
I convert a mp4 file which has a size of 166MB into .ts files (with all segments associated)
It takes more than 900 seconds, and that's above the limit for a lambda timeout.

Also my goal is to encode mp4 videos of a maximum size of 4go... and it would be to encode within 900 seconds maximum for each resolution.

I used this website to find some parameters: https://docs.peer5.com/guides/production-ready-hls-vod/

These are my parameters given to ffmpeg:

```
"ffmpegParams": [
    "-vf",
    "scale=-2:1920",
    "-c:a",
    "aac",
    "-ar",
    "48000",
    "-c:v",
    "h264",
    "-profile:v",
    "main",
    "-crf",
    "20",
    "-sc_threshold",
    "0",
    "-g",
    "48",
    "-keyint_min",
    "48",
    "-hls_time",
    "4",
    "-hls_playlist_type",
    "vod",
    "-b:v",
    "5000k",
    "-maxrate",
    "5350k",
    "-bufsize",
    "7500k",
    "-b:a",
    "192k",
    "-hls_segment_filename",
    "/tmp/1080p_%03d.ts",
    "/tmp/1080p.m3u8"
]
```

Also I tried with these parameters '-vcodec', 'libx264', '-preset', 'ultrafast' and it made it faster but it is not enough...

Maybe there's something wrong with my command. If someone could maybe enlighten me ? :)

Edit: I ended up using an EC Fargate, perfect for this kind of need.

Comment: ffmepg take the time its needs. If its to long for lambda, then you cant use aws lambda...

Comment: I understand but I have to do it with a lambda, so I need to figure out a way. Maybe by splitting my file into several chunks and encode each of them...

Comment: For long tasks like this, I would recommend having background workers to deal with such things. Using lambda for long-running tasks is only going to cost you more and eventually, more time.